# Synonym request [tag:svfr] for [tag:special-vfr]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I am missing the required 5 upvotes, so if a moderator could kindly create the synonym [svfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svfr) for [special-vfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-vfr), this would be appreciated.

Related: Is there a way to automatically link tags, i.e. If a question is marked with [specials-vfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specials-vfr), the tag [visual-flight-rules](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-flight-rules) is automatically added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done: [svfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svfr) → [special-vfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/special-vfr)

There is no way to add a tag based on the presence of another tag (e.g. add [vfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vfr) if [svfr](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svfr) is present) -- Tags that warrant such treatment are *usually* meta tags and historically [those made Jeff cry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) so they're discouraged, as is any feature that might enable them.
(This happens to be a rare exception, but the exceptions are rare enough that the feature isn't likely to get added…)