# What does tag score mean?

Tags: support

[image]

Both tags now have questions with +5 votes. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work):

> Users with more than 2500 reputation (1250 on beta sites) and a total
>   answer score of 5 or more on a given tag may suggest synonyms for that
>   tag.

So you as a user would need to have an answer score (total upvotes minus downvotes) of 5 or more on [md-80](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/md-80) to suggest a synonym for it. It still needs 4 others that also have a score of 5 or more to vote to be approved.

If you don't meet that requirement (or even if you do), you can [post a question here on meta](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1510/1696). If a mod agrees with your suggestion they can make the change. It also allows discussion, as some synonyms are not as straightforward as they seem at first glance.

Comment: I've always thought that was a rather odd requirement. Seems like anybody with sufficient rep ought to be able to *suggest* a synonym whereas you should only need a score in the specific tag to *approve* it. But that's just my opinion. The tags need some cleanup but I doubt many of us have enough points in all the tags to do it